# Difference between "def" and "static def" in Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

As the title, what is exactly the difference of these two *defs* in Groovy?

Maybe it's a documentation problem, I can't find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method declaration without `static` marks a method as an instance method. Whereas a declaration with `static` will make this method static - can be called without creating an instance of that class - see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/

`def` in groovy defines a value as duck typed. The capabilities of the value are not determined by its type, they are checked at runtime. The question if you can call a method on that value is answered at runtime - see [optional typing](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#_optional_typing).

`static def` means that the method will return a duck typed value and can be called without having instance of the class.

Example:

Suppose you have these two classes:

```
class StaticMethodClass {
    static def test(def aValue) {
        if (aValue) {
            return 1
        }
        return "0"
    }
}

class InstanceMethodClass {
    def test(def aValue) {
        if (aValue) {
            return 1
        }
        return "0"
    }
}
```

You are allowed to call `StaticMethodClass.test("1")`, but you have to create an instance of `InstanceMethodClass` before you can call `test` - like `new InstanceMethodClass().test(true)`.